# .NET ComponentModel.DataAnnotations RegularExpression not working with BsonIgnoreExtraElements

Tags: .net, regex, data-annotations, bson

I have to put DataAnnotations on certain fields to block scripts being passed in API request.
I am using Regular expression annotation and it is working in 3 Model classes however, it is not working for following class.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class Folder
    {
        private string _path = "";
        /// <summary>
        /// Unique identifier of the tenant.
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public int TenantId { get; set; }  
        /// <summary>
        /// Unique identifier of the folder.
        /// </summary>
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string _id { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the folder.
        /// </summary>
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Name must be alphanumeric")] 
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        /// <summary>
        /// Description of the folder.
        /// </summary>
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9., ]*$", ErrorMessage = "Description can contain Alphabets, Numbers, Fullstop and Comma only.")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the group for the folder. In case of multiple folder belongs to same group. 
        /// </summary>
        [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$", ErrorMessage = "GroupName must be alphanumeric")]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
```

I think this is because of the BsonIgnoreExtraElements, this is not there in other Model classes.
The controller of this Model is shared below.

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    [AdminAccessFilter]
    [HttpPut]
    [PUT("tenants/{tenantId}/collab/v1/folders/{folderId}")]
    public async Task<Folder> EditFolderAsync(int tenantId, string folderId, Folder folder)
    {
        folder.FullPath = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folder.GroupName) ? (folder.GroupName + "/") : "") + (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folder.Path) ? (folder.Path + "/") : "") + folder.Name;
```

**Same Folder Model class is invoked in the above PUT API but the validation error is not throw! Why is the RegularExpression annotation for Name, Description and GroupName not working?**
Please help!